# reCAPTCHA without server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCAPTCHA on a Contact form (three fields, name, mail and message), and that data I store on Firebase.

My application is build with React and I used the [react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha) package to make it easier to use.

It works fine, I shows and I can click and it verifies.

In my research, I have seen people mention the secret key is important for a total check, but I am unsure how to use it. I don't really have a backend except for Firebase, and I don't think a check can be implemented there.

If I try to verify through their .../siteverify API, I keep getting CORS blocked, and I read somewhere on StackOverflow that the secret key is meant to be used on a server (so as not to expose it).

So my question is, is it enough to just include the frontend reCAPTCHA, or am I missing something to make it working properly?

Answer (score -1):

You need a server to receive a form submission that would include the captcha response. That server needs to pass that captcha response to the captcha service, who then verifies the captcha attempt and returns a success or failure.